# Linking nanogui into an OpenGL project with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, glfw

I'm trying to add nanogui to my OpenGL project that already uses glfw. There is an example showing exactly how to do so in the documentation but I can't replicate it outside of this sample project.

My problem arises at the linking step:

```
Error LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall nanogui::Screen::Screen(void)" (??0Screen@nanogui@@QAE@XZ)
```

The incriminated line is `nanogui::Screen * screen = new nanogui::Screen();`, the only one referring to the library.

The problem seems quite obvious, the compiler understands that I'm going to need the nanogui functions and expects the linker to figure out where the code for those functions is, except the linker fails.

This is what I have done:

- Included nanogui.h in my main.cpp
- Added the path to it in project setting->C/C++->general->Additional Include Directories. This explains why the compilation part works
- Added the path to nanogui.lib in project settings->Linker->input->additional Dependencies. That SHOULD resolve my problem but it doesn't.

What baffles me is that I am able to compile the library from source and run the sample projects. There must be some kind of parameter / flag I am missing but I can't figure it out. I played a little with the preprocessor flags from the sample projects without luck.

EDIT: The [sample project](https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui/blob/master/src/example3.cpp) I manage to run when I'm using the project provided by the author and generated with CMake but cannot replicate outside of it.

Comment: There's two parts to linking. 1) Setting the path where libraries can be found, and 2) Telling the compiler what it needs to look for. Have you added nanogui.lib to the additional dependencies or used #pragma comment(lib, ...) to bring it in?

Comment: Yes I added it to the additional dependencies (Edited a bit my question, I had written it but it wasn't very clear) but didn't use the pragma. Am I supposed to use both?

Comment: `Added the path to nanogui.lib in project settings->Linker->input->additional Dependencies.` All you add there is the filename, `nanogiu.lib` just like kernel32.lib, user32.lib, etc. You should have added the library path to the VC++ Directories->Library Directories entry, where you added the include directory. You can use the pragma or additional dependencies, but you don't need both.

Comment: Actually you can put the full path in `settings->Linker->input->additional Dependencies`. That's what I did for glfw for example and that works even though it is probably bad practice.
I tried your way for nanogui without much success. It's so weird, the sample projects work. There is obviously something I'm missing here.
Thank you for your help anyway, it rules out things I might have done wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the library for x64 instead of the default x86. Just run cmake with (a variation of) `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..`, i.e. explicitly specify `Win64`. You can then simply build the NanoGUI.sln in Visual Studio and link against the resulting nanogui.lib. If you don't specify the target with cmake, you only get the Win32 option as your build target, which is not supported according to the documentation.

Comment: Haha maybe that was it. I have no way to try today. I think I ended up using Nuklear instead :).

Comment: Yeah, I already guessed this wouldn't really be helpful to you specifically 3 years later, but I ran into the exact same problem and found this question via google, so I thought I'd leave this answer here for future people to find.